# Spring boot, how to disable autoconfiguration of springSecurityFitlerChain

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, configuration

I'm studying the Spring Security framework with Spring Boot, and one thing I dislike about boot is it's obscurity. There's so much magic happening, troubleshooting and customization is trial and error, guessing what is configured automatically and where. This is high risk in the security field, as misconfigured system may be compromised.

I would like to replace `springSecurityFilterChain` with my own implementation. In vanilla Spring I would register `DelegatingFilterProxy` with a different name in `web.xml`, and implement corresponding bean. However, Spring boot apparently registers `springSecurityFilterChain` automatically if jars are present, and now I'm not sure if the auto configuration will back of just by declaring the `springSecurityFilterChain` in a traditional way, or will this lead to misconfigured system?

Generally, I would like to understand Spring boot better, and not just guessing what is happening, where and how to take control of that area.

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of preconfigured things, but you can override every single step. The magic of `@EnableAutoConfiguration` is just convenience. The `--debug` switch should tell you more what is happening in the background.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html

Answer (score 3):

If you use Spring Boot 1.4.x (I'm not sure about previous releases), one of the following would work.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration.class})
```

OR

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration.class})
```

OR

In your application.properties file,

> spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration

Sometimes you may need to exclude the `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration`  class as well.

Comment: Still autoconfiguring. Now I'm concerned, if just the presence of EnableWebSecurity annotation registers the security filter. But then again, why would we need AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer in vanilla spring, as @EnableWebSecurity was already present. Does it have something to do with embedded servlet container?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to disable the whole security chain? I don't see the use case, but if, then you do not need `@EnableWebSecurity` at all. If you only want to adjust the chain, create a Class annotated with `@Configuration` and `@EnableWebSecurity` which is extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. There you can tell who is allowed to do what by overriding `configure(HttpSecurity)`.